# Contrary of .join() pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

`join` returns an RDD containing all pairs of elements with matching keys.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.join

Example:

```
 trueDupsRDD = (rdd1.join(rdd2))
```

**How can I perform a disjoin?**

I tried:

```
notMatchingRDD = (rdd1.join(!rdd2))
```

Comment: What about some application of `rdd1.filter` for data that is not in `rdd2`?

Answer (score 5):

Use `subtractByKey`:

> Return each (key, value) pair in C{self} that has no pair with matching
>   key in C{other}.

```
rdd1.subtractByKey(rdd2)
```